# Why in between #define is code highlighting turned off in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, syntax-highlighting

I'm using `#ifdef macroIsFreeVersion` `#endif` to insert code that is only specific to a lite version of my app. When I write code in between these statements it seems like code highlighting and syntax warnings are turned off.

Why is this?

I'm setting the macro in the build settings

[image]

Comment: Define `macroIsFreeVersion` when you're working with that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode highlights the code based on the result of the `#if` directive. Any part that is "false" isn't highlighted because that code will be compiled out. If you switch targets to the "lite" version, you should see the opposite highlighting.

This feature makes it easy to see if the `#if` is currently correct or not based on the current target and the values of any "defines" used inside the `#if` block.

Comment: weird, is seems to be doing the opposite, I have the lite version selected I'm using #ifdef macroIsFreeVersion #endif #ifndef macroIsFreeVersion #endif. The code is highlighted in the #ifndef section not the ifdef section